# How to do map of map processing in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I have a csv as shown below,

```
T1,Data1,1278

T1,Data1,1279

T1,Data1,1280

T1,Data2,1283 

T1,Data2,1284  

T2,Data1,1278

T2,Data1,1290
```

I want to create JavaPairRdd as Map of Map like below

```
T1,[(Data1, (1278,1279,1280)), (Data2, (1283,1284))]
T2,[(Data1, (1278,1290))]
```

I tried to use combinebykey to create a `JavaPairRDD` using the below code

```
JavaPairRDD<Timestamp,List<Tuple2<String,List<Integer>>>> itemRDD = myrdd.mapToPair(new PairFunction<Row, Timestamp, Tuple2<String,Integer>>() {
    @Override
    public Tuple2<Timestamp, Tuple2<String, Integer>> call(Row row) throws Exception {
        Tuple2<Timestamp, Tuple2<String, Integer>> txInfo = new Tuple2<Timestamp, Tuple2<String, Integer>>(row.getTimestamp(0), new Tuple2<String, Integer>(row.getString(1), row.getInt(2)));
        return txInfo;
    }
}).combineByKey(createAcc,addItem,combine)
```

But I am not able to create a PairRdd like above. Whether my approach is correct? whether combinebykey can be used to create map of map in spark?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `cogroup` method instead of `combineByKey`.